# Can MSISDN only be fetched by a WAP website?

Tags: android, iphone, http, wap, msisdn

I have a requirement to get MSISDN (phone number) of the person who will be visiting it from a Android or iPhone. I know I can get the MSISDN from the HTTP headers.

I want to know that if I already have **contracts with mobile carriers** then can i get the MSISDN from a full fledged HTML website or do i need to make a WAP only site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the headers, if they are there, regardless of the technology used on the client side.  Server side you just need to pluck out the headers you want.  They'll be there whether or not it's a WAP or HTML request, as both are HTTP.  WAP/WML is a markup language much like HTML, the requests for WAP pages are to the best of my knowledge still HTTP.

*Disclosure: I work on such projects.*

Original Answer Below, left as it may prove useful to 'those that come after'

You can't get the MSISDN from the HTTP headers unless:

- Something has gone horribly wrong, see O2 MSISDN leak.  When their filter started adding the MSISDN as a header to all websites rather than their own stuff.
- You have a really dodgy provider.
- You have an agreement with a particular network provider to insert those headers for visitors to your system from their network.

For more information see [Mobile Subscriber Leakage in HTTP](http://blog.jgc.org/2012/02/mobile-subscriber-leakage-in-http.html), or google around.  The hit rate you achieve capturing such information will be very very low.

To the best of my knowledge WAP is no different.  The privacy implications are huge and such leakage would be soundly and rightfully condemned by the public.

Also :

[The Register](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/01/25/o2_hands_out_phone_numbers_to_websites/)

Comment: didn't you read the question... we have an agreement to get MSISDN.. what i want to know is does my site has to be WAP or we can create full html5 compliant website?

Comment: Aha, I think I missed an edit, didn't notice the word contract in there before!